# multi-item-carousel not working when I use it in bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, carousel, react-bootstrap

1. In my react project I use bootstrap
   and when I use react multi-item-carousel and in output, only some dots are showing.
2. And when I use multi-item-carousel in another project in which there was no bootstrap used then Carousel appears as expected.

So why Carousel not showing properly in my first project?
Please help me

1st result--

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvvIj.png)

2nd result (expected)--

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTeqo.png)

Following code, I used in both projects.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Carousel from 'react-multi-carousel';

class Simple extends Component {
  
  
  render(){
    const responsive = {
      superLargeDesktop: {
        // the naming can be any, depends on you.
        breakpoint: { max: 4000, min: 3000 },
        items: 5
      },
      desktop: {
        breakpoint: { max: 3000, min: 1024 },
        items: 3
      },
      tablet: {
        breakpoint: { max: 1024, min: 464 },
        items: 2
      },
      mobile: {
        breakpoint: { max: 464, min: 0 },
        items: 1
      }
    };
  return (
    <div>
      <Carousel responsive={responsive}>
  <div>Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
  <div>Item 3</div>
  <div>Item 4</div>
</Carousel>;
    </div>
  );
}
};

export default Simple;
```

Comment: Please, provide your sample code not working, and the tests you have done

Comment: @Sourcerer please see result and code

Comment: Much better! I'm not an expert in Bootstrap and/or React. I was only moderating posts, and I see not enough information to provide an answer. With your addendums, will be easier for you to get a valid answer.

Comment: And, trying to help, will be easier if you add also the generated HTML. Seeing the images, it seems you have an inheritance class in bootstrap. Do you know how to use Chrome to debug CSS classes attributes?

Comment: @Sourcerer No I don't know. Actually issue in my react app is, does not applying CSS of react-multi-carousel while I importing it.